# How to switch dictation language in Yosemite using a voice command?

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

I write in both English and French, and quite often I need to switch between them. I'd like to know if I can achieve this using a voice command?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any keyboard shortcut to do so but as a pis aller you can create a [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) script that switches from  English to French, and another one that switches from French to English, then bind those two scripts to a voice command.